# More than 24 hours in a day in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, intervals

Assuming I have this schema:

```sql
create table rental (
    id           integer,
    rental_date  timestamp,
    customer_id  smallint,
    return_date  timestamp,
);
```

Running this query returns strange results:

```sql
select customer_id, avg(return_date - rental_date) as "avg"
from rental
group by customer_id
order by "avg" DESC
```

It displays:

```
customer_id|avg_rent_duration     |
-----------|----------------------|
        315|     6 days 14:13:22.5|
        187|5 days 34:58:38.571428|
        321|5 days 32:56:32.727273|
        539|5 days 31:39:57.272727|
        436|       5 days 31:09:46|
        532|5 days 30:59:34.838709|
        427|       5 days 29:27:05|
        555|5 days 26:48:35.294118|
...

599 rows
```

Why is there values like `5 days 34:58:38`, `5 days 32:56:32` and so on? I thought there where only 24 hours in a day, maybe I'm wrong.

### EDIT

Demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/caa7a/1/0

Sample data:

```
insert into rental (rental_date, customer_id, return_date)
values
('2007-01-02 13:10:06', 1, '2007-01-03 01:01:01'),
('2007-01-02 01:01:01', 1, '2007-01-09 15:10:06'),
('2007-01-10 22:10:06', 1, '2007-01-11 01:01:01'),
('2007-01-30 01:01:01', 1, '2007-02-03 22:10:06');
```

Comment: you can use `justify_interval()` to normalize the interval

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you, it seems to work! Could you please elaborate (how/why) and post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe The issue isn't that the difference isn't a round number of days. It's that the number of hours often exceeds 24, as in `5 days 34:58:38`; the question is why that's not `6 days 10:58:38`.

Comment: I strongly suspect this has to do with the use of `avg`; the subtraction may be correct, but `avg` causes problems. I'm not certain of this, though.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to adjust interval with `justify_interval()` function:

```
select customer_id, justify_interval(avg(return_date - rental_date)) as "avg"
from rental
group by customer_id
order by "avg" DESC;
```

See [official doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html):

> Adjust interval using `justify_days` and `justify_hours`, with additional sign adjustments

Still, it does not explains **why** the result of the operation is that weird without using `justify_interval()` (in other words, why we have to apply this function)

*Note: thanks to [@a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) for their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57822113/more-than-24-hours-in-a-day-in-postgresql/57824161#comment102074687_57822113)*

Answer (score 5):

This is an attempt to explain the behavior.

PostgreSQL intervals don't get “justified” more than necessary during interval arithmetic. I'd say that has two reasons:

- speed
- loss of exactness (e.g. when days are being converted by months, assuming a month to have 30 days

So you get results like this:

```
SELECT INTERVAL '1 day 20 hours' + INTERVAL '5 days 30 hours';

    ?column?     
-----------------
 6 days 50:00:00
(1 row)
```

The same holds for division:

```
SELECT INTERVAL '6 days 50 hours' / 2;

    ?column?     
-----------------
 3 days 25:00:00
(1 row)
```

Always adjusting the hours to be less than 24 would make a long calculation like the `avg` you are calculating unnecessarily complicated, and as you have found, there are functions to adjust the result.